# Two sliders which are connected to give other values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a loan calculator based on two sliders. I feel I'm nearly there but the syntax is letting me down plus one last formula.

I have two sliders, one which represents the loan amount, the other represents the loan length.

Here is a bit of the code to highlight all the calculations. I think there are errors here too.

```
function update() {

     $amount = $("#slider1").slider("values", 100);

     $interest = $amount / 100 * 15 ;

     $perday = 15 ;      

     $apr = (($interest / $amount) / ("#slider2"/365) * 10000) / 100;

     $amount2 = $amount + $interest;

     $("#amount").val($amount1);

     $("#amount2").val($amount2);

     $("#amount3").val($interest);

}
```

Interest is charged at 15% of the amount borrowed.
Each day is worth 15p so in order to get my final charge.

[15% of the loan amount total]
– [0.15p per day credit]

I have developed a fiddle but its not correct, hence why I'm here.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnystudent/VycW2/)

How can I get both the sliders to work together so that if I move the top or bottom slider, it will affect the overall loan amount and Interest?

Any help will be most appreciated. I'm really struggling with this one.

Comment: What are the actual formulas/calculations that the results should be based on? You have two sliders but I'm left to wonder where the actual computation should come from.

Comment: I suppose the master slider would be the loan amount one. So it's the loan amount which will control the calculation.

Comment: The finance charge = 15% + .15p per day based on the borrowers chosen loan term.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net , can include slider css from a CDN. There is no class `loanamount` in your markup but one slider calcs are looking for it. Also your calc functions aren't looking at values of the other slider. Very hard to understand what relationship needs to be between sliders as far as calcs go

Comment: Why don't you create just one slider (showing two values) instead of linking two different sliders?

Comment: `($interest / $amount) / ("#slider2"/365)` looks like a syntax error to me

Comment: Hi Bergi, one slider is for the loan amount, the other slider for the days the loan has been taken out for.

Comment: Is this the functionality you require? http://jsfiddle.net/kUWYK/

Comment: Nearly there. How can I get it to work with the Loan Length slider.  If you read above you'll see that each day is worth 15p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***I believe this is what you want - jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/VycW2/17/) <- follow link

```
function update() {            
     $interest = 0.15 ;
     $perday = 15 ; 
     $amount1 = $("#amount").val();
     $dayscount = $("#days").val();
     $amount2 = parseInt($amount1) + $interest * parseInt($amount1) + (parseInt($dayscount) * ($perday/100));
     $("#amount2").val($amount2);
     $("#amount3").val(parseFloat($amount2-$amount1).toFixed(2));
}
```

Fixed your update algorithm and your slider handlers

I considered that you last 2 fields (Your Loan & Interest) are the final value to be paid and the difference between the value to be paid and the value borrowed respectively. If this interpretation is not what you intended please comment.

**UPDATE 1**

Here I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VycW2/19/). Beware that I don't know what the APR is, so validate that my calculation are right. I also did not use any rounding, cause I don't know if you need it like this

**UPDATE 2**

Updated with new [**formula here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VycW2/20/). I still have no idea if this is right or not

Comment: Whooop there it is! :) Thats correct J.  There is one thing though which I forgot to add and that was the APR.  You can see in post that I've done the calculation.  By law, APR needs to be seen by the consumer.  I know the formula to work it out.  Just how do I calculate it in Javascript and then output it in a text field.

Comment: Excellent Santos, although the calculation is strange going from one day to two days +, the APR jumps by nearly half for some reason.  Any ideas?  It's nothing to do with the decimal.

Comment: Please be more explicit. Which calculation is strange? The APR? I'm not sure what APR is, so I can't validate the calculations. Maybe I used $amount1 instead of $amount2. Not sure which one should be used

Comment: Sorry, when you adjust the loan amount higher, the APR, which is the (Annual Percentage rate) should go higher too.  This is actually going down for some reason.  I f I adjust the days, the APR should go lower.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you could do something like this:

```
function update() {
    var interest = 0.15;
    var sliderAmount = parseFloat($("#slider1").slider("option", "value"));
    var days = parseFloat($("#slider2").slider("option", "value"));
    var perday = 15 * days ;
    var interestAmount = sliderAmount * interest * days;
    $("#amount1").val(sliderAmount);
    $("#amount2").val(sliderAmount);
    $("#amount3").val(interestAmount+ perday);
}
```